# My for loop only allows one post to be displayed, over and over again

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop

```
    
  /* To sort the id and limit the post by 40 */
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM requests"; 
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $sqlall= "SELECT * FROM requests ";
  $resultall = $conn->query($sqlall);
     
  $i = 0;
     
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  
    
      // Output data of each row
      $idarray= array();
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<br>";  
          
          // Create an array to store the
          // id of the blogs        
          array_push($idarray,$row['id']); 
      } 
  }
  else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
?>
          <?php 
            for($x = 1; $x < 40; $x++) {
              // This is the loop to display all the stored blog posts
              if(isset($x)) {
                $query = mysqli_query(
$conn,"SELECT * FROM `requests`");
                  
                $res = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                $email1 = $res['email1'];
                $msg1= $res['msg1'];
                $subject1 = $res['subject1'];
                $name1 = $res['name1'];
                $id = $res['id'];
```

the output is 40 cards reading data from the first row in my database. can anyone help?
I'm using xampp.
This code is to show the loop, but if anyone wants the full code is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13tT3eds6mgmIFIl4dh3bIfEDesYSokOo/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You are storing all the IDs in the array `$idarray` and then you just run 40 times the same query again and always extract the same fist row.

Comment: @AllanSharad did the answer below help you? If so please remember to mark it as accepted and/or upvote it. If it's not helping please explain why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing all the IDs in the array `$idarray`, but then you don't really use them properly. You loop over them, but you just run `SELECT * FROM` requests` 40 more times, and always extract the same first row. You never use the ID to change the query.

But it really makes no sense to run lots of separate queries anyway. If you just want the first 40 rows then use MySQL's `LIMIT` keyword. It usually works best when combined with `ORDER BY` as well. Something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM requests ORDER BY id LIMIT 40";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($res = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $email1 = $res['email1'];
  $msg1 = $res['msg1'];
  $subject1 = $res['subject1'];
  $name1 = $res['name1'];
  $id = $res['id'];

  //example output, just for demo:
  echo $email1." ".$msg1." ".$subject1." ".$name1." ".$id;
}
```

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html